# Zeo server not starting (unconnected) disconnected

Tags: python, plone, zope

We are using plone 4.3.3 with python 2.6.7
for scripts we use virtualenv with python 2.6.7

We invoking zeo server as ./bin/zeo start (from the virtualenv) and it is giving this error repeatedly and then terminates.

OK the ZEO server does not terminate, but something wrong is happening here because my site is down and the pages show:
503 Service Unavailable - No server is available to handle this request.

There were issues with python environment, everything (almost) was working with python 2.7.6 on ubuntu then it was upgraded to 2.7.12; things started to happen bad; and this night i revert back, rebuild again python 2.7.6 based virtualenv.

zeoserver.log:

```
2016-11-18T12:14:46 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 51988): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 51988)>
2016-11-18T12:14:46 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 51989): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 51989)>
2016-11-18T12:14:46 new connection ('127.0.0.1', 51990): <ManagedServerConnection ('127.0.0.1', 51990)>
2016-11-18T12:14:46 (127.0.0.1:51988) received handshake 'Z3101'
2016-11-18T12:14:46 (unconnected) disconnected
2016-11-18T12:14:46 (unconnected) disconnected
```

Any ideas what to check for to get more info and fix the issue?

Instance log:

```
2016-11-18T11:19:00 INFO ZEO.zrpc.Connection(C) (127.0.0.1:8000) received handshake 'Z3101'
------
2016-11-18T11:19:00 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage Server authentication protocol None
------
2016-11-18T11:19:00 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage Connected to storage: ('localhost', 8000)
------
2016-11-18T11:19:00 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage No verification necessary -- empty cache
------
2016-11-18T11:19:04 INFO ZEO.ClientStorage zeostorage Disconnected from storage: "('localhost', 8000)"
```

I started zeo fg and instance fg separately and its my instance thats breaking:

```
ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "/data/hiding/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.EasyNewsletter-2.6.15-py2.7.egg/Products/EasyNewsletter/browser/configure.zcml", line 50.2-55.32
ImportError: cannot import name IDisableCSRFProtection
```

What does it indicate?

Thanks

Comment: Try with `./bin/zeo fg`

Comment: Thanks, I already tried but the same behavior and same error in log : zeoserver.log

Comment: The log seems normal... You can get more info editing `parts/zeo/etc/zeo.conf` and changing the loglevel from info to debug. What does the `instance.log` says?

Comment: Thank you all, my problem is solved. For future references for others I paste other useful discussion: https://community.plone.org/t/zoe-server-not-starting-python-cron-job-not-working/3055

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add the follwing to your buildout

```
# add this to your egg-section of the instance    
eggs =
    .....
    plone4.csrffixes

[versions]
plone.keyring = 3.0.1
plone.locking = 2.0.9
plone.protect = 3.0.19
```

It looks like a missing package. In the [Products.EasyNewsletter](https://github.com/collective/Products.EasyNewsletter/blob/master/plone-4.3.x.cfg) are the requirements pinned.Look also at the [plone4.csrffixes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone4.csrffixes/1.1) package.

Comment: Thanks you are right and this has fixed the problem.
Here is the link I followed as advised by mr cwd9 -- https://pypi.org/project/plone4.csrffixes/